# Stopping the background music when starting a game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I have background music which starts when the app is launched in GameViewController.swift using the following code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

// VARIABLES
var backgroundMusicPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

// AUDIO PLAYER
func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    var error : NSError? = nil
    do {
        backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        backgroundMusicPlayer = nil
    }
    if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
        print("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}

func stopBackgroundMusic() {
    backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playBackgroundMusic("MainTheme.mp3")

<< Various irrelevant code >>
}
```

Because this is run in the viewController, it persists through changing scenes on the menu (i.e. opening the "shop" scene) and creates a seamless track.  When I click the "Play" button on the menu scene I want the music to then stop, and transition to the game.  I have the stopBackgroundMusic() method in the GameViewController but I don't know how to call it on on the menu scene.  *IN THE MENU SCENE* I tried this:

```
// TOUCH
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
    if touchedNode.name == "startGame" {
        GameViewController.stopBackgroundMusic()
        let transitionType = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2)
        let viewSize = self.view?.bounds.size
        let scene = GameScene(size: viewSize!)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transitionType)
    }
}
```

But I get an error saying I'm missing parameter #1 in call for stopBackgroundMusic() which shouldn't require any parameters.  Am I calling this method wrong?   Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to play MP3s throughout your app or just on the `GameViewController`?

Comment: I want the GameScene to play its own MP3s but otherwise just the GameViewController

Comment: I added the audio player to the view controller so that it would continue playing when the scenes changed.  I just need it to stop playing when a certain scene, GameScene, is presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to your class by using GameViewController but your function is at the object instance level.

If you declare the variable and function at the class level, your code in the touchesBegan function should work fine.

```
static var backgroundMusicPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
class func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) ...
class func stopBackgroundMusic()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   GameViewController.playBackgroundMusic("MainTheme.mp3")

  << Various irrelevant code >>
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is perfect (: